# How to use jQuery ui-icon locally?

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to use the [jQuery Modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) , it's works fine like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But when I save them locally, the close icon is missing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery-ui.css" /> 
<script src="Styles/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Styles/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I inspect the html I could see:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" unselectable="on">close</span>
```

I also found it ui-icon-closethick in jquery-ui.css, but I cant find a way to save the icon locally

I found the Icon [here](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc5/tests/static/icons.html).

Comment: There should be an images folder under Styles

Comment: what do you mean please explain

Comment: Stumbled into the same problem applying SSL. [2 years later]

Comment: @JeffreyGoines this is why i asked this question lol i had to save the files locally or ssl would block non secure ressources

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi you can go to this site http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ there in the left side press the button "Download theme" and select the smoothness theme that you want.

- Then you can go and unzip the downloaded file.
- Go to css/smoothness/.. and copy all its content to your "Styles" folder.
- Replace your referenced css with the css names of the downloaded files.
- **Remember don't move the images folder from your "Styles" folder** if you want to move it you have to change some paths in the css files.

Answer (score 1):

Save this image (http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc5/themes/base/images/454545_256x240_icons_icons.png) and put it in your local directory. You don't wanna edit their CSS... so because the icons are in images folder on their server (images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png), you should create a similar folder called "images" in the same directory you have your css, so in your case it would be Styles.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the jquery ui website http://jqueryui.com/download/ and create your custom package. When you download it you can use it locally. You have than all images and other files like css, js etc.